# Conditional probability of 3 continuous random variables

Tags: probability

The length of time for events X, Y, Z to occur are independent and have probability density functions
$f(x)$, $f(y)$ and $f(z)$. What is the probability that given the second event occurred at time $t$, find the probability that Y occurred at time $t$.

If it was about the first or last event I would do something like $Pr(Y=t|min(X, Y, Z) = t)$ but not sure about this scenario.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the probability of $Y$ occurring at time $t$ and Y is the second event. Therefore, the probability is $Pr(Y=t|X<Y \land Z>Y) + Pr(Y=t|Z<Y \land X>Y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Does Pr(Y = t ∧ X < Y ∧ Z > Y) = Pr( X < t, Z > t) = Pr(X < t) Pr(Z > t)?

Comment: Not true. $X<Y \land Z>Y$ or $Z<Y \land X>Y$ only says that $Y$ is the second event. It should also satisfy that event $Y$ takes place at time $t$.

Comment: How could I solve this probability equation? Use conditional probability formula? Sorry I am new to probability and have been stuck on this question for a while.

Comment: @Sophie You can refer to [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: Ah yes that makes a lot of sense. Would the Y in the denominator Pr(X < Y ∧ Z > Y) affect the independence? Is it just equal to Pr(X<Y) * Pr(Z>Y). Thank you

Comment: Yes, $X<Y$ and $Z>Y$ are independent, if $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ are mutually independent.